# Triangle Inequality Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality, absolute-value

my confusion arises when trying to derive $|a-b|\ge|a|-|b|$
My first attempt was to derive it using the triangle inequality i.e $|a-b| = |a+(-b)|\le|a|+|-b|=|a|+|b| since |a|=|-a|$ this is obviously wrong. So what I did next was try deriving it straight from first principles however I get two different answers when doing it from first principles

**Frist Result:**
$$|a-b|^2=(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2\\
=|a|^2+|b|^2-2ab\ge |a|^2+|b|^2-2|a||b|
=(|a|-|b|)^2\\
\implies|a-b|^2\ge(|a|-|b|)^2\implies|a-b|\ge|a|-|b|
$$ wich is the correct answer. however we can do this In a different way

**Second Result:**

$$|a-b|^2=(a-b)^2
=a^2+2a(-b)+(-b)^2\\
=|a|^2+|-b|^2+2a(-b)
\le|a|^2+|-b|^2+2|a||-b|\\
=(|a|+|-b|)^2=(|a|+|b|)^2 
\textrm{ since } 
|-b|=|b|
\implies|a-b|^2\le(|a|+|b|)^2\\
\implies|a-b|\le|a|+|b|
$$ which is the result I got above in my first try.

Im not sure where im making a mistake in these calculations, however it seems like the two things contradict each other. Help would me much appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Apply the triangle inequality to $|b + (a-b)|$.

Comment: I don't see why you think there is a contradiction there, you just have inequalities in different directions. Your second result $|a-b| \leq |a| + |b|$ is just the normal triangle inequality. This limits how large $|a-b|$ is. The first inequality limits how small $|a-b|$ can be.

Comment: Let O be the origin of that space, then apply the standard metric.

Comment: So, it's $d(a,b)\ge d(O,a)-d(O,b)$. really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt was in a wrong direction since when proving 
$$
|a-b|\geq |a|-|b|\tag{1}
$$
you want a *lower* bound for the quantity $|a-b|$. But they way in your attempt gave an *upper* bound for $|a-b|$.

The fact that 
$$
|a-b|\leq |a|+|b|\tag{1'}
$$
is **not** a contradiction to (1); it is nothing but *another* fact.

For example the fact that $|4-(-1)|\leq |4|+|-1|$ does **not** contradict $|4-(-1)|\geq |4|-|-1|=3$.

You may rewrite (1) as
$$
|a|\leq |a-b|+|b|,\tag{2}
$$
and if you apply the triangle inequality to $|(a-b)+b|$, you would get (2).